# Validation Implementation fails in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I am trying to implement form validation using Hibernate, in my spring-mvc

application. I have applied a single @Size constraint on the 'name' field

of my form. When I submit the form, I'm getting the following error :

java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence has interface org.hibernate.ejb.AvailableSettings as super class

My code :

//////////////////////////SpringConfig//////////////////

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "com." })

@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
    @Autowired
    private PersonService ps;

    @Bean @Autowired
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(Person.class);
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("admin123");
        return dataSource;
    }
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(
                "/resources/*");
    }
    @Bean @Autowired
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver res = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        res.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        res.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return res;
    }


    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        return properties;
    }
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }
```

///////////////////////////////////Controller///////////////////////////

```
package com.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.model.Person;
import com.service.PersonService;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService ps;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView listPersons(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
        List<Person> listper = ps.list();
        model.addObject("personsList", listper);
        model.setViewName("index");
        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/newPerson", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newPerson(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Person p = new Person();
        model.addObject("person", new Person());
        model.setViewName("AddPerson");

        return new ModelAndView("AddPerson", "person", new Person());

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/save",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@Valid @ModelAttribute Person p,BindingResult result) {
        //System.out.println(p.getName());
        // ps.getPersonById(p.getId());
        if(result.hasErrors())
        {
            return  "redirect:http://localhost:8080/MainAssignment3/AddPerson";
        }
        else
        {       
        ps.save(p);

        return "redirect:http://localhost:8080/MainAssignment3/";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping("/removePerson")
    public String remove(HttpServletRequest req) {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("id"));
        ps.removePerson(id);
        return "redirect:http://localhost:8080/MainAssignment3/";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/update")
    public String update(@ModelAttribute Person p) {
        System.out.println(p.getName());
        // ps.getPersonById(p.getId());
        ps.save(p);

        return "redirect:http://localhost:8080/MainAssignment3/";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/updatePerson")
    public ModelAndView updatePerson(HttpServletRequest req, ModelMap p) {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("id"));
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        String address = req.getParameter("address");
        String gender = req.getParameter("gender");
        String salary = req.getParameter("salary");

        p.addAttribute("id", id);
        p.addAttribute("name", name);
        p.addAttribute("gender", gender);
        p.addAttribute("address", address);
        p.addAttribute("salary", salary);

        return new ModelAndView("updatePerson", "person", p);

    }
}
```

////////////////////////////////DAOImplementation////////////////

```
package com.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.model.Person;

@Transactional
@Repository
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO, java.io.Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(PersonDAOImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf) {
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }

    public void save(Person p) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
        s.saveOrUpdate(p);
        tx.commit();
        s.close();

        System.out.println("Record successfully inserted");

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public List<Person> list() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Person> personsList = session.createQuery("from Person").list();
        for (Person p : personsList) {
            logger.info("Person List::" + p);
        }
        return personsList;

    }

    public void updatePerson(Integer id) {
        Session session = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory()
                .openSession();
        Person p = new Person();
        Person person = session.get(Person.class, p.getId());


        //Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Person");
        person.setName(p.getName()); // modify the loaded object somehow
        session.update(person);
        //t.commit();
        session.close();

    }

    public Person getPersonById(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Person p = (Person) session.load(Person.class, new Integer(id));
        logger.info("Person loaded successfully, Person details=" + p);
        return p;
    }

    public void removePerson(Integer id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

//      Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        Person p = (Person) session.load(Person.class, new Integer(id));
        session.delete(p);
//      t.commit();
        logger.info("Person deleted successfully, person details=");

    }



}
```

/////////////////////////////////Model//////////////////////////////

```
package com.model;



import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;




@Entity
//@Table(name="person")
public class Person {

    @Id 

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

    @Column(name = "id")

    private Integer id;
    @Size(min=5, max=10, message="Your name should be between 5 - 10 characters.")

    private String name;

    private String address;
    private int salary;
    private String gender;
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Column(name="name")//@NotNull(message = "The name must not be null")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

///////////////////////messages.properties file///////////////////

Size.person.name=Name must be between {5} and {10} characters long

/////////////////////////////index.jsp///////////////

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
 <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>


<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
    <h2>Hello World!</h2>

<h3><a href="/MainAssignment3/newPerson">Add Person</a></h3>
    <table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>address</th>
    <th>gender</th>
    <th>salary</th>

</tr>   
 <c:forEach var="person" items='${personsList}' varStatus="status">
    <tr>

        <td>${person.id}</td>
        <td>${person.name}</td>
        <td>${person.address}</td>
        <td>${person.gender}</td>
        <td>${person.salary}</td>
        <td>
        <a href="/MainAssignment3/updatePerson?id=${person.id}&name=${person.name}&address=${person.address}&gender=${person.gender}&salary=${person.salary}">Edit</a>
            <a href="/MainAssignment3/removePerson?id=${person.id}">Delete</a>
        </td>

    </tr>

</c:forEach> 


</table>

    </body>
</html>
```

///////////////////////////////////AddPerson.jsp//////////////////////

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add Employee</title>
</head>
<body>

<form:form action="/MainAssignment3/save"  method="post" modelAttribute="p">
        <!-- <input type="hidden" name="id" > -->
        name : <input type="text" name="name"> <br/>
        address : <input type="text" name="address" ><br/>
        gender : <input type="text" name="gender" ><br/>
        salary : <input type="text" name="salary" ><br/>
        <input type="submit"value="submit">
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it work without validation?

Comment: yes, it works perfectly without validation

Comment: any idea about this??

Comment: no - its generating a class - but has the wrong heirarchy. Try putting NotNull or another annotation as a test. Probably some conflict on the dependencies

Comment: okay. I will make that change

Comment: same error : java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence has interface org.hibernate.ejb.AvailableSettings as super class

Comment: Can you check the pom.xml? I checked it but I think the versions of the dependencies have been specified properly

Comment: you are mixing various versions. you are using entity manager of version 4.X.X and validation of version 5.X.X. please update your entity manager version and try again.